# Encode a String in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need HTML ENCODE in JavaScript (client side) a String (where User could insert HTML TAGS) from a TextBox so bypassing Reqeust.Validation.

Javascript should Encode string and Display it Encoded in Label.

```
       <asp:TextBox ID="uxValueInput" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
       <br />
       <asp:Label ID="uxResultEncoded" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
       <asp:Button ID="uxEncodeButton" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

I am new in JavaScript and I have tried different scripts on a web but with no success.
Could you please post a really simple example so I would be able to understand how could work. Thanks!

Comment: Don't. If you need it encoded in a consistent way, then do it on the server where you have complete control over it. ASP.NET isn't bad enough to prevent you doing that, surely?

Comment: Sorry guys I need HTML ENCODE a string!

Comment: To David. I need by pass Request.Validation for ASP.NET I cannot disable it at Page Level. Let me know if you have any idea thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm with David Dorland: Don't do this client-side, instead disable request validation ([here's an article saying how](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/02/20/tip-48-ndash-disable-request-validation.aspx)). But if you do that, be **sure** you also use [Anti-XSS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814) or similar libraries to prevent exactly what it is that ASP.Net is trying to protect you from.

However, if you have a genuine use-case for doing *minimal* HTML-encoding on the client, you can do this:

```
var escapes = {
    '<': '&lt;',
    '>': '&gt;',
    '&': '&amp;'
};
var raw = "Hi, I'm an <scr" + "ipt src='http://evil.example.com/attack.js'><\/script> evil & malicious attack.";
var encoded = raw.replace(/[<>&]/g, function(m) {
    return escapes[m];
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/agetu3)

Here's how that works:

1. We have a map called `escapes` which maps the raw character to the HTML entity for it (so maps `<` to `&lt;`, etc.).
2. Our raw string has a malicious script.
3. We use `String#replace` and a regular expression to search for all `<`, `>`, and `&` characters and replace them with their equivalent entity. When you pass a function into `String#replace` as the second argument, it gets called for each match and uses the return value as the replacement. The regex, `/[<>&]/g`, means "find `<`, `>`, or `&` *globally* (the `g` flag) within the string".

Comment: Thanks T.J. but I CANNOT disable request validation and I need ENCODE HTML with Javascript. Do you know how to do it? It should be pretty easy.. but I never done any Javascript so i need your help :-)

Comment: @GIbboK: Just added a very basic example.

Comment: @GIbboK: No worries, I just added an explanation as well. But again, **do** look at that article in hopes that you can do this another way. It offers a code-level solution, not `machine.config` solution. Best,